# Using AJAX to get data from a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, ajax

I'm trying to use AJAX to help me retrieve data from my PHP array. I want to be able to enter a name, and get out the corresponding number. I've played around with W3schools AJAX PHP code, but don't know how to change it to give me the corresponding number I'm looking for? My array looks like this:

```
$a = array(
"Sarah" => 1,
"Sam" => 12,
"Tim" => 2,
"Tom" => 13,
 };
```

So when I being to type in S, the output would give me the numbers 1 and 12.
Can anyone guide me towards the correct way of doing this? The current code I have is from here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your reference link I have written this answer, use same HTML and JavaScript just replace the PHP with

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showHint(str) {
    if (str.length == 0) { 
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "get_hint.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Start typing a name in the input field below:</b></p>
<form> 
First name: <input type="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
</form>
<p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p>
</body>
</html>

<?php
// Array with names
$a[] = "Anna";
$a[] = "Brittany";
$a[] = "Cinderella";
$a[] = "Diana";
$a[] = "Eva";
$a[] = "Fiona";
$a[] = "Gunda";
$a[] = "Hege";
$a[] = "Inga";
$a[] = "Johanna";
$a[] = "Kitty";
$a[] = "Linda";
$a[] = "Nina";
$a[] = "Ophelia";
$a[] = "Petunia";
$a[] = "Amanda";
$a[] = "Raquel";
$a[] = "Cindy";
$a[] = "Doris";
$a[] = "Eve";
$a[] = "Evita";
$a[] = "Sunniva";
$a[] = "Tove";
$a[] = "Unni";
$a[] = "Violet";
$a[] = "Liza";
$a[] = "Elizabeth";
$a[] = "Ellen";
$a[] = "Wenche";
$a[] = "Vicky";

// get the q parameter from URL
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

$hint = "";

// lookup all hints from array if $q is different from "" 
if ($q !== "") {
    $q = strtolower($q);
    $len=strlen($q);
    foreach($a as $name) {
        if (stristr($q, substr($name, 0, $len))) {
            if ($hint === "") {
                $hint = array_search($name, $a);
            } else {
                $hint .= ", " . array_search($name, $a);
            }
        }
    }
}

// Output "no suggestion" if no hint was found or output correct values 
echo $hint === "" ? "no suggestion" : $hint;
?>
```

output

[image]

and for your case.

```
<?php
// Array with names
$a = array(
"Sarah" => 1,
"Sam" => 12,
"Tim" => 2,
"Tom" => 13,
 );
// get the q parameter from URL
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

$hint = "";

// lookup all hints from array if $q is different from "" 
if ($q !== "") {
    $q = strtolower($q);
    $len=strlen($q);
    foreach($a as $key=>$name) {
        if (stristr($q, substr($key, 0, $len))) {
            if ($hint === "") {
                $hint = $name;
            } else {
                $hint .= ", " . $name;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Output "no suggestion" if no hint was found or output correct values 
echo $hint === "" ? "no suggestion" : $hint;
?>
```

output

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your array declaration is incorrect:

```
$a = array(
    'Sarah' => 1, //to make array associative you need to put key => value
    'Sam' => 12,
    'Tim' => 2,
    'Tom' => 13
);
```

And it returns both numbers because both start with 'S'. If you want to evaluate complete name you need to do this:

```
$numbers = [];

foreach($a as $key => $value) {
    if($key == $queryName)
        $numbers[] = $value;
}

echo $numbers;
```

This should return an array with numbers which coincide exactly with your request.

Comment: How are the numbers separated?