# Fix live search app and turn it from single to multiple choice

Tags: javascript, php, multiple-choice, livesearch

I have written these two files today, but it doesn't work yet (a curtain with the suggested result should appear). I'm almost sure that it needs little fixes at most, but can't work out which ones :-(
More, I absolutely have no idea on how to get it to allow multiple choices. The best would be that I click on the suggested word, then I type in a comma and a space as token/separator, than another word to search and so on.
Any idea/suggestion?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function showResult(str) {
      if (str.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border = "0px";
        return;
      }

      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML = this.responseText;
          document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border = "1px solid #A5ACB2";
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET", "livesearch.php?q=" + str, true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <p><b>Start typing a name in the input field below:</b></p>
  <form>
    <input type="text" size="30" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)">
    <div id="livesearch"></div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

---

```
<?php
// Array with names
$a[] = "Anna";
$a[] = "Brittany";
$a[] = "Cinderella";
$a[] = "Diana";
$a[] = "Eva";
$a[] = "Fiona";
$a[] = "Gunda";
$a[] = "Hege";
$a[] = "Inga";
$a[] = "Johanna";
$a[] = "Kitty";
$a[] = "Linda";
$a[] = "Nina";
$a[] = "Ophelia";
$a[] = "Petunia";
$a[] = "Amanda";
$a[] = "Raquel";
$a[] = "Cindy";
$a[] = "Doris";
$a[] = "Eve";
$a[] = "Evita";
$a[] = "Sunniva";
$a[] = "Tove";
$a[] = "Unni";
$a[] = "Violet";
$a[] = "Liza";
$a[] = "Elizabeth";
$a[] = "Ellen";
$a[] = "Wenche";
$a[] = "Vicky";

// get the q parameter from URL
$q = $_GET["q"];

$hint = "";

// lookup all hints from array if $q is different from "" 
if ($q !== "") {
    $q = strtolower($q);
    $len=strlen($q);
    foreach($a as $name) {
        if (stristr($q, substr($name, 0, $len))) {
            if ($hint === "") {
                $hint = $name;
            } else {
                $hint .= ", $name";
            }
        }
    }
}

// Output "no suggestion" if no hint was found or output correct values 
echo $hint === "" ? "no suggestion" : $hint;
?>
```

Comment: You'll be much more likely to get an answer if you do more than copy/paste code from another answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36001640/3650835). What have you tried? What console/php errors occur? What occurs in general? What are your ideas for getting it to work? etc.

Comment: @mplungian - oh, sorry, but actually it isn't exactly copied from another answer since I found its parts on two different examples of w3school (https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp) and I'm trying to mesh them together if possible - I also found (stackoverflow.com/a/36001640/3650835) on google before asking but I've understood that haven't exactly the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, it seems to me I've found a solution. I actually have to put all pieces together but theoretically it should work.
There is a library, scriptoculous, which has a function (ajax.autocompleter()) which does exactly what I'm looking for. For more reference watch here: http://www.codicefacile.it/tutorials/tutorials.php/52/Ajax_Autocompleter_nei_nostri_form
I've been reading that since it uses prototype.js as a library to work it will conflict with other applications of the same page which use jquery.js instead. But the following workaround should fix it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3641464/9016436